# How to subset a dataframe iteratively based on all unique values within a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe `df` as per the below. Each ticker has a value for all months, and I am wanting to subset this big dataframe into 12 dataframes for each month.

```
| month | value | tickr |
|-------|-------|-------|
| 10-22 | 100.2 | ALPHA |
| 11-22 | 164.9 | DEEBO |
| 12-22 | 197.5 | PAUIS |
| 01-23 | 154.4 | ALPHA |
| 02-23 | 256.4 | ILKON |
| 03-23 | 312.0 | OLAPH |
| 04-23 | 199.3 | LIMON |
| 05-23 | 239.7 | BUNGO |
| 06-23 | 102.6 | SEMAK |
| 07-23 | 208.1 | ALPHA |
| 08-23 | 211.0 | ALPHA |
| 09-23 | 175.6 | LIMON |
...
```

I know I can just do something simple like `oct22 = df[df['month'] == "10-22"]` and repeat it 11 more times, but I am wanting to do something that can iterate on its own and output these dataframes independently. Any suggestions on this?

It would be preferable if this can be done in a for-loop, because as I understand, the dataframes produced wouldn't be stored in memory so I can perform further analysis on them and then save down the final result for a faster-performing code.

Comment: If you set a variable like `oct22`, you want to split your data per month AND per year, no?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than create 12 dataframes, use the index to easily split your data when you needed:

```
idx = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%m-%y').dt.strftime('%b%y').str.lower()
df.index = idx
```

Usage:

```
# I slightly modified your example
>>> df.loc['oct22']

       month  value  tickr
oct22  10-22  100.2  ALPHA
oct22  10-22  124.8  GAMMA
oct22  10-22  115.7  OMEGA
```

Or create a `select` custom function:

```
def select(mth):
    dt = pd.to_datetime(mth, format='%b%y').to_period('M')
    return df[df['month'] == dt]

df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%m-%y').dt.to_period('M')
```

Usage:

```
>>> select('oct22')
      month  value  tickr
0   2022-10  100.2  ALPHA
12  2022-10  124.8  GAMMA
13  2022-10  115.7  OMEGA
```

Answer (score 1):

I would convert [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) and use this a grouper:

```
group = (pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%m-%y')
           .dt.to_period('M')
         )

for k, g in df.groupby(group):
    print(f'Group: {k}')
    print(g)
```

Output:

```
Group: 2022-10
   month  value  tickr
0  10-22  100.2  ALPHA
Group: 2022-11
   month  value  tickr
1  11-22  164.9  DEEBO
Group: 2022-12
   month  value  tickr
2  12-22  197.5  PAUIS
Group: 2023-01
   month  value  tickr
3  01-23  154.4  ALPHA
Group: 2023-02
   month  value  tickr
4  02-23  256.4  ILKON
Group: 2023-03
   month  value  tickr
5  03-23  312.0  OLAPH
Group: 2023-04
   month  value  tickr
6  04-23  199.3  LIMON
Group: 2023-05
   month  value  tickr
7  05-23  239.7  BUNGO
Group: 2023-06
   month  value  tickr
8  06-23  102.6  SEMAK
Group: 2023-07
   month  value  tickr
9  07-23  208.1  ALPHA
Group: 2023-08
    month  value  tickr
10  08-23  211.0  ALPHA
Group: 2023-09
    month  value  tickr
11  09-23  175.6  LIMON
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for _, sub_df in df.groupby('month'):
    print(sub_df)
    # doing something with sub_df
```

The groupby() function is used to perform grouping operations on the DataFrame, grouped according to the values of the 'month' column, and the result is stored as an iterator object. Use a for loop to iterate through this iterator object, each time a sub-data frame is taken out and printed. Where sub_df represents one sub-data frame that has been taken out at each time. In this loop body, some processing or calculations can be performed on each sub-data frame.